# Push all x element to the end of the array in O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve an algorithm task but unfortunately cannot come up with some optimal approach for it. We are given an array and the task is to move all elements `x` at the end of the array. For e.g. 
Input `[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,5]` 
Output `[2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 1, 1]`

Comment: Show us what you've attempted so far

Comment: Does it *have* to be an array? (Not a linked list, for example?)

Comment: @adam.kubi it have to be an array or Linked list ?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it have to be array

Comment: Seems simple enough, I suggest you try using a loop or two. (just not nested loops as this is likely to be O(N^2))

Comment: @PeterLawrey: you hint is about as useful as saying "solve it by yourself".

Comment: The outline of the algorithm is to scan the array left to right, maintaining two indexes: copy-from and copy-to. Every time you meet a non-1, copy it and increment copy-to. If you meet a 1, do nothing. In the end, copy-to tells you how many 1's to append.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it's not mean to be useful. It is meant to say that if your solution looks complicated you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Rearrange
{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,5};
        reArrange(arr, 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    private static void reArrange(int[] arr, int x) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int current : arr)
            if (current != x)
                arr[index++] = current;
        Arrays.fill(arr, index, arr.length, x);
    }

}
```

Output

```
[2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 1, 1]
```

Comment: plus 1, I took the liberty of shortening it a little.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `C++` implementation of algorithm that I came up with. I am not sure about correctness but I tested it for different `x` and it worked. You can figure out the algorithm from this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
void swap (int a[], int i, int j) {
    int temp;
    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
void move_to_end(int a[], int x, int size) {
    bool flag = 0;
    int s_i;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(flag) {
            if(a[i] != x) {
                swap(a, s_i, i);
                s_i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(a[i] == x) {
                flag = 1;
                s_i = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main () {
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,6,5,1,2,3};
    int size = 16;
    int x = 1;
    move_to_end(a, x, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
2 3 4 2 3 4 5 6 6 5 2 3 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To= 0;
for (From= 0; From < Length; From++)
  if (A[From] != 1)
  {
    A[To]= A[From];
    To++;
  }

for ( ; To < Length; To++)
  A[To]= 1;
```